# mouseover producing multiple images works in Firefox, but not i.e

Tags: javascript

The code below allows the user to hover over 1 object and it not only replaces the object but also shows an additional object between the buttons.

It works great in Firefox, but does not in Internet Explorer.

HELP

webpage: 
http://www.isp.ucar.edu/

Thx,
Terri

```
if ( < document.images) {

    img1on = new Image();
    img1on.src = "images/buttons/button-beachon-on.gif";
    img1off = new Image();
    img1off.src = "images/buttons/button-beachon.gif";

    img2on = new Image();
    img2on.src = "images/buttons/button-bgs-on.gif";
    img2off = new Image();
    img2off.src = "images/buttons/button-bgs.gif";

    img3on = new Image();
    img3on.src = "images/buttons/button-iam-on.gif";
    img3off = new Image();
    img3off.src = "images/buttons/button-iam.gif";

    img4on = new Image();
    img4on.src = "images/buttons/button-nvia-on.gif";
    img4off = new Image();
    img4off.src = "images/buttons/button-nvia.gif";

    img5on = new Image();
    img5on.src = "images/buttons/button-utls-on.gif";
    img5off = new Image();
    img5off.src = "images/buttons/button-utls.gif";

    img6on = new Image();
    img6on.src = "images/buttons/button-water-on.gif";
    img6off = new Image();
    img6off.src = "images/buttons/button-water.gif";

    img7on = new Image();
    img7on.src = "images/buttons/button-exploratory-on.gif";
    img7off = new Image();
    img7off.src = "images/buttons/button-exploratory.gif";


    // second image that does not appear in original button space
    img1ad = new Image();
    img1ad.src = "images/buttons/beachon-overview-sm.gif";

    img2ad = new Image();
    img2ad.src = "images/buttons/bgs-overview-sm.gif";

    img3ad = new Image();
    img3ad.src = "images/buttons/iam-overview-sm.gif";

    img4ad = new Image();
    img4ad.src = "images/buttons/nvia-overview-sm.gif";

    img5ad = new Image();
    img5ad.src = "images/buttons/utls-overview-sm.gif";

    img6ad = new Image();
    img6ad.src = "images/buttons/water-overview-sm.gif";

    img7ad = new Image();
    img7ad.src = "images/buttons/exploratory-overview-sm.gif";
}

function imgOn(imgName) {
    if (document.images) {
        document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "on.src");
        document["holder"].src = eval(imgName + "ad.src");
    }
}

function imgOff(imgName) {
    if (document.images) {
        document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "off.src");
        document["holder"].src = "images/buttons/isp-overview-sm.gif";
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the missing 'd' in 'ocuments.images' intentional ?
Also, make sure to read the FAQ about how to post code etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `eval` in these functions are totally uncalled for

```
function imgOn(imgName) {
    if ( < document.images) {
        document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "on.src");
        document["holder"].src = eval(imgName + "ad.src");
    }
}

function imgOff(imgName) {
    if ( < document.images) {
        document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "off.src");
        document["holder"].src = "images/buttons/isp-overview-sm.gif";
    }
}
```

They should read

```
function imgOn(imgName) {
    document.getElementById(imgName).src = window[imgName + "on"].src;
    document.getElementById("holder").src = window[imgName + "ad"].src;
}

function imgOff(imgName) {
    document.getELementById(imgName).src = window[imgName + "off"].src;
    document.getElementById("holder").src = "images/buttons/isp-overview-sm.gif";
}
```

And instead of multiple `img1on = new Image();` followed by calls to `window[foo]` you should do this

```
var myImages = {};
myImages["img1on" = new Image();
```

Then you can later on do

```
var foo = myImages[imgName + "on"].src;
```

to get the `src`.

Comment: Unfortunately the above gives me an image when first loaded but when rolled over it cannot find the "on" & "ad" images and after I am off the item the original images do not reappear (which was actually my problem at the beginning).

Any other ideas?

Thank you so very much for looking at this.
Terri

Comment: Test:
isp.ucar.edu/index3.php

Comment: Tried a slight mod: Rollovers work but does not go back to the original images.


function imgOn(imgName) {
    document.getElementById(imgName).src = eval(imgName + "on.src");
    document.getElementById("holder").src = eval(imgName + "ad.src");
}

function imgOff(imgName) {
    document.getELementById(imgName).src = imgName + "off.src";
    document.getElementById("holder").src = "images/buttons/isp-overview-sm.gif";
}

isp.ucar.edu/index4.php

Comment: Thank you Sean. I am really rusty so I will play with your updates when I am more awake.   :)